# Is it possible to check if a value already exists in a table?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out a method that sees if a value (a id) already exists in a database table. I want to do this using Angular, but I can't seem to find any information about this.

Comment: By table, you mean an array? `array.indexOf(value) >= 0`? `array.some(function(v) {return v.id === value;});`?

Comment: use a loop to check whether it exist or not

Comment: We're going to need some more information. Generally, in angular, a table is going to be made up of a iteration over an array, or something similar. So are you checking for data in that array?

Comment: By table I mean a table of a database. I have a table with movie records. All the movies have a unique id. I want to check with Angular if an id already exists in that table.

Comment: Angular is a JavaScript framework for creating in-browser web applications. The database is on the other side of the planet, on a server, queried by a web server, queried by Angular. Angular doesn't care or even know about your database. It just queries RESTful web services of your web server. It's up to the web server to query the database.

Comment: Requesting the movie data through a JSON function and then check if the movie id is in that data is not the way to go then?

Comment: So, in short, send a http request to /movies/1234. If you get the movie, it exists. If you get a 404, then it doesn't. Of course, you need to design the REST service behind this URL accordingly.